# Retrieve Entry from Database where time value is null

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to update a row in a database where one of the values for a date/time is empty.

The code I have below gives the error:- Parameter ?_2 has no default value.

Does anyone know how to work with null / empty values?

Cheers

```
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*) from DI WHERE [Task] = ? AND [Time_Off] = ?", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "DI"));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", null));
int count = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

if (count > 0)
{
    OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE DI SET [Time_OFF] = ? WHERE [Task] = ? AND [Time_Off] = ?", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
    com1.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay));
    com1.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "DI"));
    com1.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", null));
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
    DIPerson = DIlist[DIcomboBox.SelectedIndex];

    OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DI ([Person], [Task], [Time_On]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
    com2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DIPerson.ID));
    com2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "DI"));
    com2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay));

    com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: It must be "[Time_Off] is null" AND if you want to specify a parameter, most likely you need DBNULL not null

Comment: @Anthony Elaborate, and make it an answer.

Comment: Won't DBNull.value works?

Comment: If I use the DBNull it says:- Type used as Variable, Any other ideas?

Comment: Remove the parameter and write directly in the query Is Null.

Comment: You can change your SQL using is null or is not null as your wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*) from DI WHERE [Task] = ? AND [Time_Off] is null", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "DI"));
int count = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

if (count > 0)
{
    OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE DI SET [Time_OFF] = ? WHERE [Task] = ? AND [Time_Off] is null", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
    com1.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay));
    com1.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "DI"));
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
    DIPerson = DIlist[DIcomboBox.SelectedIndex];

    OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DI ([Person], [Task], [Time_On]) VALUES     (?, ?, ?)", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
    com2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DIPerson.ID));
    com2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "DI"));
    com2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay));

    com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```